# grep string equivalent in windows 7 to 10

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I want to find a command in windows equivalent to the following command in linux:

```
cat file.txt | grep -oP '\d{5}-\d{5}'
```

Out

```
99527-86793
```

with:

```
findstr /R "pattern" file.txt
```

I try this but it works partially.

```
findstr [0-9]-[0-9] file.txt
```

Out:

```
de4f2114-847c-4cf2-8a0b-a38d04c0fdac1/1
99527-86793
```

How can I delimit the output to only those numbers: start and end 5 numbers 0 to 9 - 5 numbers 0 to 9 ?

thk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
findstr [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] file.txt
```

You may also be interested in [grep for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>findstr doesn't extract matches. It only returns the string it finds.</strike> I recommend using powershell when dealing with regex. You can do something like:

```
select-string -Path 'c:\input.txt -Pattern '\d{5}-\d{5}' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > 'c:\output.txt'
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7

EDIT: I was incorrect that findstr cannot return matches but I still recommend using powershell for regex.

Comment: thanks for your command, but I prefer to do it in cmd - batch

Comment: in that case I recommend iskyfire answer above.